# How to increase the accurancy of an image classifier?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I made a model that can classify 82 number with a dataset of images (around 10500 images)
the dataset is in Two folders :
**the first folder the train folder has 8000 images in 82 folders**
**the Second folder the test folder has 2000 images in 82 folders**
I have tested the model on 2 other folders before going to the main dataset folder and **it worked fine**
but here I don't know why the acc won't get better
**Please note that not all folders in my dataset has the same number of images neither the resolution of images is the same, but all around 210x50**
**also please note** that in my first try when i used the model to test it on the two folders i made the small dataset of two classe with the same number of images  in the folders (same for the validation folder)
bellow the **code** that I used to create the model:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K


# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 251, 54
#img_width, img_height = 150, 33

train_data_dir = 'C:/Users/ADEM/Desktop/msi_youssef/PFE/test/numbers/data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'C:/Users/ADEM/Desktop/msi_youssef/PFE/test/numbers/data/valid'
nb_train_samples = 10435
nb_validation_samples = 2051
epochs = 20 # how much time you want to train your model on the data
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.05,
    horizontal_flip=False)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save('first_try.h5')
```

and here the result:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:74: The name tf.get_default_graph is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:517: The name tf.placeholder is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:4138: The name tf.random_uniform is deprecated. Please use tf.random.uniform instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3976: The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:133: The name tf.placeholder_with_default is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.placeholder_with_default instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3445: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\optimizers.py:790: The name tf.train.Optimizer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.train.Optimizer instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:3376: The name tf.log is deprecated. Please use tf.math.log instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_impl.py:183: where (from tensorflow.python.ops.array_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.where in 2.0, which has the same broadcast rule as np.where
Found 10435 images belonging to 82 classes.
Found 2051 images belonging to 82 classes.
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:986: The name tf.assign_add is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign_add instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:973: The name tf.assign is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.assign instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:2741: The name tf.Session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.Session instead.

Epoch 1/20
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:174: The name tf.get_default_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.get_default_session instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:181: The name tf.ConfigProto is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:190: The name tf.global_variables is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.global_variables instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:199: The name tf.is_variable_initialized is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.is_variable_initialized instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\ADEM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py:206: The name tf.variables_initializer is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.variables_initializer instead.

652/652 [==============================] - 43s 65ms/step - loss: -625.7214 - acc: 0.0143 - val_loss: -632.8458 - val_acc: 0.0112
Epoch 2/20
652/652 [==============================] - 47s 72ms/step - loss: -627.1426 - acc: 0.0143 - val_loss: -632.6816 - val_acc: 0.0113
Epoch 3/20
652/652 [==============================] - 42s 65ms/step - loss: -627.8743 - acc: 0.0143 - val_loss: -633.1438 - val_acc: 0.0113
Epoch 4/20
652/652 [==============================] - 45s 69ms/step - loss: -627.0466 - acc: 0.0142 - val_loss: -632.6816 - val_acc: 0.0108
Epoch 5/20
652/652 [==============================] - 47s 73ms/step - loss: -628.4401 - acc: 0.0143 - val_loss: -632.7599 - val_acc: 0.0118
Epoch 6/20
652/652 [==============================] - 45s 69ms/step - loss: -626.8264 - acc: 0.0143 - val_loss: -631.9844 - val_acc: 0.0108
Epoch 7/20
652/652 [==============================] - 55s 85ms/step - loss: -627.8007 - acc: 0.0141 - val_loss: -636.2931 - val_acc: 0.0103
Epoch 8/20
652/652 [==============================] - 46s 71ms/step - loss: -626.7282 - acc: 0.0144 - val_loss: -633.0968 - val_acc: 0.0123
Epoch 9/20
652/652 [==============================] - 47s 72ms/step - loss: -628.2569 - acc: 0.0143 - val_loss: -633.8959 - val_acc: 0.0113
Epoch 10/20
652/652 [==============================] - 46s 71ms/step - loss: -627.1006 - acc: 0.0144 - val_loss: -629.7360 - val_acc: 0.0113
Epoch 11/20
652/652 [==============================] - 54s 83ms/step - loss: -627.1028 - acc: 0.0142 - val_loss: -636.8650 - val_acc: 0.0098
Epoch 12/20
652/652 [==============================] - 45s 70ms/step - loss: -627.8524 - acc: 0.0143 - val_loss: -627.5894 - val_acc: 0.0118
Epoch 13/20
652/652 [==============================] - 46s 70ms/step - loss: -627.1357 - acc: 0.0142 - val_loss: -631.9687 - val_acc: 0.0118
Epoch 14/20
652/652 [==============================] - 48s 73ms/step - loss: -627.5105 - acc: 0.0146 - val_loss: -638.9724 - val_acc: 0.0118
Epoch 15/20
652/652 [==============================] - 46s 70ms/step - loss: -629.0591 - acc: 0.0136 - val_loss: -630.7622 - val_acc: 0.0103
Epoch 16/20
652/652 [==============================] - 46s 71ms/step - loss: -625.9115 - acc: 0.0147 - val_loss: -630.3392 - val_acc: 0.0098
Epoch 17/20
652/652 [==============================] - 45s 70ms/step - loss: -627.0184 - acc: 0.0144 - val_loss: -636.2304 - val_acc: 0.0123
Epoch 18/20
652/652 [==============================] - 47s 72ms/step - loss: -626.8828 - acc: 0.0144 - val_loss: -634.5618 - val_acc: 0.0118
Epoch 19/20
652/652 [==============================] - 45s 70ms/step - loss: -627.3642 - acc: 0.0140 - val_loss: -629.8300 - val_acc: 0.0118
Epoch 20/20
652/652 [==============================] - 46s 71ms/step - loss: -627.4297 - acc: 0.0142 - val_loss: -637.6797 - val_acc: 0.0108
```

Comment: Is this a binary or multi-class classification problem? How many classes do you have?

Comment: Based on the question, it should be a multi-class classification problem. There should be 82 classes. Have you tried changing the class_mode from binary to the 82 types of digits? You can see a simple example here: https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/multi-label-image-classification-tutorial-with-keras-imagedatagenerator-cd541f8eaf24

Comment: please check my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your model now is handling a multi-class problem, a few changes need to be made:

- The loss should be `categorical_crossentropy` rather than `binary_crossentropy`
- The final activation function should be softmax rather than sigmoid
- There should be 82 neurons in your final layer (`Dense(82)` instead of `Dense(1)`) if there are 82 classes.

Good luck!

Comment: i will be testing this and refer back to you , thank you for your help and your time , hope you have a blessed day !

Comment: it worked ! but the only thing that needed to be change is the ``` binary_crossentropy``` 
you need to change it to << sparse_categorical_crossentropy >> not <<categorical_crossentropy >> or you will get the error : 
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_10 to have shape (80,) but got array with shape (1,)

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @danielcahall I have corrected the model and now it works the only things that i have changed were :

- The loss should be `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` rather than
  `binary_crossentropy`
- The final activation function should be `softmax` rather than `sigmoid`
- There should be 82 neurons in your final layer `Dense(82)` instead of
  `Dense(1)` if there are 82 classes.
  bellow the full corrected code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K


# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 251, 54
#img_width, img_height = 150, 33

train_data_dir = 'C:/Users/ADEM/Desktop/msi_youssef/PFE/test/numbers/data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'C:/Users/ADEM/Desktop/msi_youssef/PFE/test/numbers/data/valid'
nb_train_samples = 8800 #10435
nb_validation_samples = 1763 #2051
epochs = 20 # how much time you want to train your model on the data
batch_size = 32 #16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(80)) #1
model.add(Activation('softmax')) #sigmoid

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])#categorical_crossentropy #binary_crossentropy

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.1,
    zoom_range=0.05,
    horizontal_flip=False)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save('testX_1.h5') #first_try
```

**Please Note:** i have reached an `acc: 0.6675` if you want more you need to increase the **epochs**!

Answer (score 0):

**Quick UPDATE** tested the **epochs** with **30** and now the acc is :
`acc: 0.7562 - val_loss: 0.1268 - val_acc: 0.9688`